# Python multiprocessing shared variable list can't append

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to do multiprocessing with Python and there is a variable that needs to be shared across all instances. 
The variable to be shared is a list that stores variables of types by appending some user-defined class

```
<class 'output_handlers.email_output_handler.email_output_handler'>
<class 'output_handlers.dw_output_handler.dw_output_handler'>
```

as seen from print(type(var)).

I attempted to use a Manager to append the same variables to it's generated list before passing it into the threads:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
...
man = Manager()
output_handlers = man.list()
output_handlers.append(variable)
```

The above yields error `TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object` even though it can append simple types like integers and chars.
Attempting to do

```
tmp = []
tmp.append(variables)
output_handlers = man.list(tmp)
```

also yields the same error.

I also wanted to use multiprocessing.Value() to explicitly make the list sharable, but I never found the ctype code for the list

Can anyone help out with this problem?

Comment: clearly you have a `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object` object somewhere in the data you are putting in the shared list and it isn't supported (cannot be serialized)

Comment: If your task is IO-bound instead of CPU-bound consider using [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html) instead.

Comment: You may consider using redis to share some in-memory variables between multiple instances